# Не могу взять изображение из pictureBox'a для последующей проверки по пикселю

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawbitmap

Не могу понять как правильно в событии `MouseDoubleClick` взять нарисованое `Bitmap` изображение и в последствии прогнать по пиксельно и изменить цвет. Подскажите пожалуйста, [ссылка на проект GitHub](https://github.com/selt007/NNHopfild/tree/master/NNHopfild). 
Сложность заключается в том что я не могу поменять цвет каждого пикселя (то есть при двойном нажатии ничего не происходит), а при попытке напрямую работать с `Bitmap` изображением появляется исключение (добавляю в начало события строку: `bmap = new Bitmap(panel.Image);`): `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Заранее спасибо))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NNHopfild
{
    public partial class NNHT : Form
    {
        Point CurrentPoint;
        Graphics g;
        Bitmap bmap;

    public NNHT()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bmap = new Bitmap(panel.Width, panel.Height);
        panel.MouseDown += panel_MouseDown;
        panel.Paint += panel_Paint;
        g = panel.CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmap))
            {
                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, e.X, e.Y, 10, 10);
            }
            panel.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPoint = e.Location;
    }

    private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmap, Point.Empty);
    }

    private void panel_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int height = panel.Height;
        int width = panel.Width;

        int[,] mat = new int[height, width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                Color col;
                col = bmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                if (col == Color.White)
                {
                    mat[i, j] = -1;
                    bmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Blue);
                }
                if (col == Color.Black)
                {
                    mat[i, j] = 1;
                    bmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Red);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: так а что не получается то? Ошибка выскакивает или в чем проблема?

Comment: Ну на 1ый взгляд, стоит перебирать пиксели с 0 индекса; поддерживаю вопрос -- что не так?

Comment: @Alias я откорректировал вопрос и попробовал ваш вариант начать с 0, проблема актуальна

Comment: @tym32167 дополнил вопрос

Comment: кстати, не думаю что вам критично, но штатный метод `Bitmap.SetPixel(,,)` медленный, посмотрите в сторону `Bitmap.LockBits()` и `FastBitmap`.

Answer (score 4):

Просто как пример:

Я сделал форму, где по двойному клику на picturebox рисуется квадрат

```
class MyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var box = new PictureBox();
        var image = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < 500; j++)
            {
                image.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Green);
            }       

        box.Image = image;
        box.Width = 500;
        box.Height = 500;

        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;

        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;

        box.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            for (var i = -10; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (var j = -10; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    var x = args.Location.X + i;
                    var y = args.Location.Y + j;

                    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < 500 && y < 500)
                        image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                }
            }

            box.Refresh();
        };

        this.Controls.Add(box);
    }
}
```

Получилось

[image: Результат]

Comment: спасибо) но это немного не то. Дело в том что рисование курсором мыши я реализовал по зажатой левой кнопке мыши, а вот после хотелось бы преобразовывать изображение в Bitmap и по нему проходить циклом и менять при этом цвет пикселя относительно условия

Comment: @AlexandrZemlyak Ничего не понял. Я вам написал, как менять изображение попиксельно. Причем я меняю именно bitmap в обработчике. Причем в цикле. Это прямо то, что вы мне только что написали.

Answer (score 0):

на 2ой взгляд :) давайте сравним с примером от tym32167:

- вы создаёте изображение `bmap = new Bitmap(panel.Width, panel.Height);` по размеру панели, но не назначаете его соотв. контролу `panel.Image = bmap;` -- отсюда возникает упомянутое исключение, т.к. `panel.Image` у вас видимо всё ещё `NULL`.
- после перерисовки нет вызова метода `Control.Refresh()` для
  принудительной перерисовки всего контрола; Можно более экономно
  перерисовывать: для каждой изменившейся области 
  `Control.Invalidate(Region)`, затем единственный `Control.Update()` 
  обновит только эти области.
- у вас в определённый момент зачем-то существует два одноимённых
  объекта графики:  1ый принадлежит классу формы `g = panel.CreateGraphics();` и связан с контролом (т.о. будет пытаться рисовать в пустой `panel.Image`), а 2ой пересоздаётся для рисования эллипсов `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmap)){ }` в битмап не назначенный соотв.контролу.